# No signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.makeKey()

Tags: hadoop, groovy, hbase, gremlin, titan

I've installed titan-0.5.0-hadoop2 with hbase and elasticsearch support

I've loaded the graph with

```
g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-hbase-es.properties')
==>titangraph[hbase:[127.0.0.1]]
```

and a then I loaded the test application

```
GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g)
```

Now when I'm trying to create a new index key with:

```
g.makeKey('userId').dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).unique().make()
```

and I got this error:

```
No signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.makeKey() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: every(), any()
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

Can someone help me with this ?

when I want to see the indexed keys I see this

```
g.getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class)
==>reason
==>age
==>name
==>place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely following what you are trying to do.  It appears that you loaded Graph of the Gods to `g` and then you want to add `userId` as a new property to the schema.  If that's right, then i think your syntax is wrong, given the Titan 0.5 API.  The method for managing the schema is very different from previous versions.  Changes to the schema are performed through the `ManagementSystem` interface which you can get an instance of through:

```
mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
```

The syntax for adding a property then looks something like:

```
birthDate = mgmt.makePropertyKey('birthDate').dataType(Long.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
mgmt.commit()
```

Note that `g.getIndexKeys(Class)` is not the appropriate way to get schema information either.  You should use the `ManagementSystem` for that too.

Please see the documentation [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/schema.html) for more information.

Comment: I found this right now  http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/indexes.html#graph-indexes